# Static IPv4 in QEMU

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface, qemu

I'm attempting to provide static IP addresses to the network interfaces while bringing up the QEMU images via command line.
The command is like below:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -smp 2 -hda disk.img -net nic,model=i82557b,vlan=1,macaddr=00:06:04:00:0a:01 -net user,vlan=1,net=10.10.10.1/24
```

As per this, I'm assigning one network interface whose IP address should be `10.10.10.1`

When the OS comes up, the mac address gets assigned properly. However, the IP address always defaults to `10.10.10.15`

As per the [documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/qemu-system-x86/qemu-system-x86_64.1.en.html), the X.X.X.15 is probably because of DHCP - which I do not wish to configure.

How do I provide a specfic IP address to bind to the network interface?